# 1300, "Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '\\xE2\\x96\\x88\\xE2\\x96\\x88

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have set `utf8mb4` in columns charset and db yet I am having this warning while storing info by using `pymysql`. Before every INSERT I am executing following:

```
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4')
```

It does halt query but giving warning and not inserting records. How do I resolve it. Connection is set as follows:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                     user=user,
                                     password=password,
                                     db=db_name,
                                     autocommit=True,
                                     charset='utf8mb4',
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the below:

1. Use `COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci` for the column
2. Use `varchar(size)` datatype instead of `TEXT` for the column
3. Do not use `str(column)` while reading from it, use `x.encode('utf-8')` or `decode('utf-8')`